# Python socket is not receiving data and is blocked which linux `nc` is receiving it

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to interact with a remote socket programmatically. It is working perfectly using Unix `nc` but the python's `recv()` call is blocked indefinitely.

If I do

```
$ nc remotehost.com 2000
(reply) Hello from server!!
        input your name> (i input Tom and press enter) Tom
(reply) Hello Tom
```

But if I do the same thing using python sockets, my sockets first receive call fetches `"Hello from server!!\nInput your name"` but after I send my name `Tom` to the server, my socket.recv() blocks on recv() call indefinitely instead of fetching `Hello Tom`.

My python code is as follows:

```
import socket

HOST = 'remotehost.com'
PORT = 2000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

data = s.recv(4096).decode()
print(data)

sleep(1)

name = bytes('Tom', 'utf-8')
s.sendall(name)

data = s.recv(4096) # my code stucks/block here indefinitely
message = data.decode().rstrip()
```

The output I get is:

```
b'Hello from server!!
input your name>'
<charcter blinking and stuck>
```

What might be going wrong here? Same thing is working on nc but not working in python.

Comment: Remember that you need to "press enter" after entering the name...you're not doing that in your Python code, so the server continues to wait for your input.

Comment: This was exactly the mistake I was making. Thanks for saving my day!!